# Best practices to produce JSON from NotesViews or DocumentCollections

Tags: json, rest, xpages

I'm working on a custom control that will be fed by JSON content and I'm trying to find the best approach to produce and consume it.

Let say the JSON could be from:

1. Notes View (all documents)
2. Notes View (subset of documents based on a category or filter)
3. Notes Document Collection (from database.Search or database.FTSearch)

What I have on my mind is to define some Custom Properties where I can define:

- URL that produces the JSON
- Object
- etc.

So far I'm considering:

1. REST Service control from ExtLib
2. XAgent that produces JSON
3. Domino URL ?ReadViewEntries and OutputFormat=JSON

Does anyone knows if the JSON object loaded in memory has a size limit?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: There are a couple of options to transform a document to a JSON object. You might want to read this (http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2010/01/xpages-three-ways-to-build-search.html) for inspiration. Depending on your application you should also definitely test it with large(r) result sets.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm using Tommy Valand implementation against database.search in a couple of applications. However, here I'm trying to work against Notes Views or Document Collections easily defined from Custom Properties on my Custom Control. One limitation I found with database.search or FTSearch is that by default only returns 5000 documents.

Comment: That limit can be changed by adding FT_Max_Search_Results=n to the notes.ini. Set it to 0 to remove the limit.

Comment: Thanks Mark, unfortunately this is at server level and not at application level. Do you know the if reading JSON content from URL has a size limit at Server or Browser Level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely go for the REST Service control from the Extension Library, offers by far the best combination of flexibility vs performance vs development time.

Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt  Is there any file size limitation for Json returned by these REST Services? Also, where can I find syntax for Search property and other properties? There is nothing on http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/restService_REST_Service_ddxl853

Comment: I've yet to see any limitations and I'm returning several hundred Kb of data in some requests. I suspect you'd get into reasonable performance limitations before you hit any internal system limitations.

Answer (score 2):

What about creating the JSON in the view itself and then just read the column values? http://www.eknori.de/2011-07-23/formula-magic/

Comment: Very nice tip Ulrich, but, I think using REST Service (viewItemFileService or viewJsonService service) will be a more scalable option since here I can filter the view, search and handle total of records.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I missed a very important point on my post; This custom control I'm creating needs to read JSON content from Client Side JavaScript thats why I'm I'm thinking on passing an URL (REST Service or xAgent).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse the json object using ssjs, you can fetch it using an URLConnection and put the resulting object into a repeat control using the eval statement.

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to use eval statement for security reasons. As far as I know fromJson method in SSJS is better.